# Is it secure/okay to call receipt validation API without an access token check? (in-app purchase)

Tags: api, server, in-app-purchase, jwt, access-token

I run the iOS app which only works locally (I mean, no API connection needed).

In order to add subscription feature, I recently created own Server/API for the receipt validation.

**My question is:**

Should I implement an authentication feature with an access token? (e.g. using JWT)

Is it NOT recommended to call this API without access token from the client app?

For now, I plan to use this API for ONLY the receipt validation. So when a user purchased a subscription item on the client app and try to send a receipt to a server, this is the first time to call the API. No other endpoints.

**FYI:**

There's no login feature on the client side, just creating UUID at the initial launch and saving it to a local database(Realm).

Any advice/suggestions will be greatly appreciated.